# how to convert prototype array to a json string

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular6, jsobject

I have my js object/array

```
[Containerbox-1: Array(2)
0: "textbox-3"
1: "rediobox-4"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)]
```

Who to convert this in to a string I have used the JSON.stringify(); but i get only `[]` 
I am not sure what is the problem here.

I have defined my variable `public formFieldParent = [];` like this in my component.ts. And further I push elements in it dynamically

```
if (isNullOrUndefined(this.formFieldParent[targetId])) { 
        this.formFieldParent[targetId] = []; <--- Adding key here 
      }
this.formFieldParent[targetId].push(idNm); <-- adding values here for key
```

when I console it then the output is as shown above, and returns `[]` by using `JSON.stringify(this.formFieldParent);`

what should I use to get the string of it. 
Here is the screen shot of console [image]

Comment: Youre Close.  Containerbox-1 looks like a property on your object, So you might want to do something like: `JSON.stringify(this.formFieldParent['Containerbox-1']);`

Comment: key is dynamically added to variable  and entire array is important for parent child relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have defined my variable `public formFieldParent = [];`

That's the problem. You should have used an object here, as you assign textual properties (like `Containerbox-1`) to it. The array stays empty (`length` is `0`), and that's what will be shown in the JSON. [Don't abuse arrays as objects](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)!

Comment: can i assign a '0' (zero) as a key ?

Comment: Yes, if you have actual integer-indexed elements, then you can (and should) use an array.